# Login with Facebook, Google C# wrapper library?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, facebook

Is there a single-sign-on library that can easily let me 
add a "Login with Facebook", and "Login with Google" option to my website?

(Just want a library that does login only)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look into using OAuth, that's what everything appears to be moving to.  Here are some links:

http://oauth.net/code/

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

Also, see this SO question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997172/oauth-2-0-service-provider-net-libraries